# Error with Android .getDrawable()

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to grab a reference to a given imageView's set drawable image and then print out a toast when that imageView is clicked on. However, the toast is printing out the following message: 
"android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@6ed7c4"

I'd like the readout to register as "black_knight", which is the name of the drawable (black_knight.png) in the drawables folder.

Here is the Java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.board);

        final ImageView s01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s01);
        s01.setClickable(true);
        s01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (s01.getDrawable() != (null)) {
                        String Piece3 = s01.getDrawable().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Piece3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
```

And the XML:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/s01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#AF9B60"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
        />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what? oh no sir, that's a **NO!** **NO!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here :

> String Piece3 = s01.getDrawable().toString();

Calling `toString()` method on Drawable will return string representation of drawable instead of drawable name.

Use `setTag`  method in xml for adding name of image and in code use `getTag` to retrieve name:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/s01"
    ....
    android:tag="black_knight"
    android:src="@drawable/black_knight"
/>
```

In code get image name using `getTag()` :

```
String Piece3 = s01.getTag().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm using this method I'd like to be able to dynamically set and remove tags as the images (pieces on a chessboard) move around. Is this possible with setTag, from Java?

Comment: @RU92Z: yes you can dynamically set image name using `s01.setTag(new_image_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

I donot think there is any direct way to get name of drawable image unless you stores the image name along with image.

In XML you can do the following to set image name as an additional data to imageview

```
android:tag="abc.png"
```

Programmetically setting imagename

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.img)// my image img.settag("abc.png"); // to set an image name
```

you can get the image name by using getTag()

```
String imageName = (String)img.getTag();
```